# Minimum bound involving a strongly monotone map

Tags: inequality, monotone-functions

Let $w:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ a *strongly* monotone map, that is, there exists a $\gamma>0$ such that
$$
h^\top [w(x+h)-w(x)]\geq \gamma\cdot \| h\|^2,
$$
for any $x,h\in\mathbb{R}^m$

Let $K=K^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ a positive definite matrix. I'm interested in proving that the following inequality holds:
$$
y^\top [w(x+Kh)-w(x)]\geq \gamma\cdot y^\top Kh
$$
for any $x,h\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

For the scalar case, i.e. $m=1$, the proof is pretty easy. From strong monotonicity, we have that
$$
(Kh)\cdot[w(x+Kh)-w(x)]\geq \gamma\cdot (Kh)^2,
$$
which implies
$$
w(x+Kh)-w(x)\geq \gamma\cdot Kh.
$$

Then, we can use the latter to get:
$$
y[w(x+Kh)-w(x)]\geq \gamma\cdot yKh.
$$

Is it possible to generalize for $m>1$?

Comment: Your 1-D proof is incorrect since you are assuming that $Kh > 0$ and $y>0$. In fact, it is impossible that $y^\top [w(x+h)-w(x)]\geq \gamma\cdot y^\top h$ for all $y,h$ in any dimension. Take $y = h \ne 0$ and then $y = -h$. You'll get a contradiction.

Comment: Right. I agree. Let me reformulate differently, for the moment consider just the scalar case, with $K=1$ and say $h=ah_0$, $y=bh_0$, for $h_0,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.  Which is the necessary and sufficient condition on $a,b$ that guarantees that the following holds: $bh_0[w(x+ah_0)-w(x)]\geq \gamma ab h_0^2$? I understand that $a,b$ being of the same sign is only a sufficient condition..

Answer (score 1):

Discussing only the 1D case:

Note that $K = 1$ may always be assumed (in dimensions 1 or higher), and you may write $h = ah_0$ and assume $y \in \{-1,1\}$ in 1-D.

If $y$ and $h$ are further restricted to have the same sign, the assumption $y(w(x+h)-w(x)) \ge \gamma yh$ for all $h, y, x$ implies $\frac{w(x+h)-w(x)}{h} \ge \gamma$ for all $x, h>0$ which is equivalent to $w'(x) \ge \gamma$ as soon as $w$ is smooth.

If $y, w$ are restricted to have opposite signs, the equivalent statement is $w'(x) \le - \gamma$.

If $y$ and $h$ are not restricted, no such $w$ exists, since this would imply $0 < \gamma \le - \gamma$.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. I have a last, related question. In the scalar case it can be written $y\cdot [w(x+Kh)-w(x)]=y\frac{w(x+Kh)-w(x)}{Kh}Kh=yw'(x)Kh$, where $w'(x)>0$ as a consequence of positive monotonicity. Does this generalize in higher dimension to $y^\top [w(x+Kh)-w(x)]=y^\top J(x)Kh$, where J(x) is the Jacobian of $w$, which  is positive definite by positive monotonicity?

Comment: You should make this a new question. Btw there is no reason to write $Kh$, just write $h$.